# PIL to pyvision conversion

Tags: python, image, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

How can a PIL image be converted to a Pyvision image?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyvision/index.php?title=Quick_Start_1, Pvvision image itself is PIL image.

> The Image constructor accepts
>   filenames as an argument and will then
>   load that file from the disk as a PIL image. The Image constructor
>   will also accept other python image objects. For example, if you
>   pass a numpy matrix, PIL image, or an OpenCV image to the constructor 
>   it will crate a pyvision image based on that data.